# getheaders request being ignored by peers

Tags: client, network, protocol, bitcoinj, bitcoin-sv

It seems my 'getheaders' request is being ignored by peers. I've followed the implementation: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_documentation#getheaders without success.

If I change it to 'getblocks' then it returns an inv[500] message just fine. But for some reason, it's not returning a 'headers' packet when requesting headers.

I'm connected to over 100 peers, and still no success.

Has anyone else had similar trouble before? Any guidance is appreciated.

The request values are as follows:

```
    magic=3908297187
    command=getheaders
    length=69 
    checksum=1021834552
    payload=[version=70013, hashCount=1, blockLocatorHash=[00000000839a8e6886ab5951d76f411475428afc90947ee320161bbf18eb6048], hashStop=0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000]
```

and the encoded bytes are:

```
e3e1f3e876657273696f6e000000000069000000a4d49d4e7d11010004000000000000002cb0db5d73010000000000000000000000000000000000000000ffff7f000001208d000000000000000000000000000000000000ffff0fa518f420a100ecfbdaa2585542132f626974636f696e6a2d73763a302e302e372f0000000000
```

*Just to note, when serializing, i reverse the blockLocatorHash bytes as mentioned in the wiki.*

Cheers,

Comment: It would likely help answerers if you were to share the actual request that you are sending, and the response that you are receiving.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've updated my question.

Comment: Do you get any messages in debug.log on the node you're querying, if you enable `-debug=net`?

Comment: I'm pushing the raw transaction to remote peers without response, and there's nothing to suggest the message didn't send unsuccessfully.

Comment: Voting to close as the asker clarified that they are troubleshooting communication with some altcoin client.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the magic bytes you are using isn't the Bitcoin magic bytes. You have `e3e1f3e8` but Bitcoin's network magic is `f9beb4d9`.

Comment: Sorry i should have clarified, i'm trying to connect to a BSV node